# lock-on-active not working as expected

Tags: jboss, drools, redhat, business-process-management

Rules are not fired even Once when lock-on-active is set true. Should it be fired once? I expect the Rule 1 to be fired once when using lock-on-active.

(Note: I have added the codes used to execute the rules )

### Rule

```
rule "Rule 1"

lock-on-active true
ruleflow-group "Group A"

when 
    $c: Product()
then
    System.out.println("Rule 1");
    modify($c)
    {
        setAmount(1);
    }

end


rule "Rule 2" 

lock-on-active true
ruleflow-group "Group A"

when
    $c: Product()
then
    System.out.println("Rule 2");
    modify($c){ 
        setAmount($c.getAmount()+1) 
    }


end
```

### Code for executing rules

```
   KieServices kieServices=KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kieContainer=kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
    KieSession kieSession=kieContainer.newKieSession("ksession-lockOnActive");

    Product product=new Product();
    product.setName("Book");
    product.setAmount(5);


    ((InternalAgenda)kieSession.getAgenda()).activateRuleFlowGroup("Group A");

    kieSession.insert(product);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
    kieSession.dispose();
```

Comment: None of the rules are being executed? Or is just rule #1 the problem?

Comment: None of the rules

Comment: How are you inserting your `Product` object/s? and why do you use a `ruleflow-group`?

Comment: I have edited the question with execution code.  I am trying to understand the working of ruleflow-group

Comment: The title of this thread is then misleading

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `ruleflow-group` attribute is meant to be used when using rules as part of a business process in JBPM. Latest versions of Drools have unified the behavior of `ruleflow-group` and `agenda-group`so it shouldn't matter which one you use (even though I would recommend to use `agenda-group`).

Then, the way you are using to activate a flow group doesn't seem correct to me.

This is what I would do:

1) Use `agenda-group` in your rules:

```
rule "Rule 1"
lock-on-active true
agenda-group "Group A"
when 
    $c: Product()
then
    ...
end


rule "Rule 2"  
lock-on-active true
agenda-group "Group A"
when
    $c: Product()
then
    ...
end
```

2) Before firing the rules, set the focus on the agenda group:

```
kieSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("Group A").setFocus();
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

That should do the trick.

The rules still look odd to me, but maybe is because you are just doing a POC. Just a reminder: **you shouldn't depend on the order of your rules in your DRLs to get the expected output**.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I guess, the final amount would be either 1 or 2.

Comment: I have met with issue using lock-on-active. Link for the Issue posted: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827625/understanding-lock-on-active-with-agenda-group