# understanding lock-on-active with agenda-group

Tags: java, jboss, drools, business-process-management

I tried a sample example to see how lock-on-active works. When I fire the rule without using agenda-group everything seems fine. But when i uncomment the agenda-group in the below code and set focus to group "Group B" no rules are fired.

### Rule

```
rule "Additional Rs.1 tax for books above Rs.10"

//agenda-group "Group B"
lock-on-active true
when 
    $o: Product(name=="Book",amount>10)
then
    System.out.print($o.getAmount()+"-->");

    modify ($o) {
        setAmount($o.getAmount()+1); 
    }

    System.out.println($o.getAmount());
end

rule "Additional Rs.2 tax for books above Rs.20"

//agenda-group "Group B"
lock-on-active true
when 
    $o: Product(name=="Book",amount>20)
then
    System.out.print($o.getAmount()+"-->");
    modify ($o) {
        setAmount($o.getAmount()+1); 
    }

    System.out.println($o.getAmount());
end
```

### Code used for firing rules

```
KieServices kieServices=KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kieContainer=kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kieSession=kieContainer.newKieSession("ksession-lockOnActive");

Product product=new Product();
product.setName("Book");
product.setAmount(11);

Product product2=new Product();
product2.setName("Book");
product2.setAmount(21);

kieSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("Group B").setFocus();

kieSession.insert(product);
kieSession.insert(product2);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

### Output without agenda-group

```
21-->22
11-->12
22-->23
```

Comment: You will need to come up with a self-contained test showing your problem. I was not able to reproduce it in this [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdw4mqz3qo5ulfc/my-app.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I was using older version of Drools ( 6.2.0 Final) . When I changed it to 7.4.1. The code worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using older version of Drools ( 6.2.0 Final) . When I changed it to 7.4.1. The code worked